# Can't run 'update-grub'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, mdadm, uuid

I've got some trouble with my Ubuntu-System:

```
update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: disk `mduuid/c7ac5a8fef833db7b45d6c2ebb2e20e6,1' not found.
```

But I'm still able to reboot the system without any problem.

I'm using

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

with

```
uname -a
Linux mclean 4.13.0-25-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:14:41 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The OS is on an MD-RAID0 SSD with 1 disk

```
 mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
      Container : /dev/md/ddf0, member 0
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 937164800 (893.75 GiB 959.66 GB)
   Raid Devices : 1
  Total Devices : 1

          State : clean
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 256K

 Container GUID : 4C534920:20202020:10000079:10009260:44B56FED:B97DE3B3
                  (LSI      07/11/16 23:55:57)
            Seq : 0005a12a
  Virtual Disks : 2

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
```

I've searched some hours for a solution, but nothing helps so far. I hope, you can help me.

Comment: Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/904678/update-grub-on-mdadm-raid-1

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2358512.html

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262346&page=2

Comment: I've tried this some hours ago, without succeed. The error still appears after reboot. There is no error with boot-proccess.